# Does VS 2013 SQL Server Data Tools support SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I do not have SQL Server Data Tools installed.  I would like to create a SQL Server 2008 Database project using VS 2013?  Is that possible?  We are still using SQL Server 2008 R2 for our development and production databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Sql Server Data Tools for VS2013 is compatible with Sql Server 2008 R2. This is our setup here and it works flawlessly.

In fact, according to [this FAQ found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh322942), SSDT supports Sql Server 2005 as well so I wouldn't worry too much about obsolescence for now.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link, I looked all over for documentation that would tell me that.